# F2PY returns ValueError: invalid version number '4.'

Tags: python, mingw, fortran, python-2.7, f2py

I am new to Python and want to be able to use my existing Fortran code and run it from Python. I am trying to compile a small "Hello world" Fortran program using F2PY by following instructions online.

I am working on Windows. So far I have installed Python 2.7.3, NumPy 1.6.1, SciPy 10.1, and MinGW 4.8.

I then tried (amongst other things)

```
f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 --fcompiler=gnu95 -m foo foo.f90
```

This reports an invalid version number.

> ValueError: invalid version number '4.'

If anyone could suggest what is going wrong and what I would need to change to get this to run I would be most grateful. The full output from F2PY is follows:

```
D:\python\fortran2>f2py.py -c --compiler=mingw32 --fcompiler=gnu95 -m foo foo.f90
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "foo" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7\foomodule.c
creating c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c
creating c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'foo.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: foo
                        Block: hello
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "foo"...
                Constructing wrapper function "hello"...
                  hello()
        Wrote C/API module "foo" to file "c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7\foomodule.c"
  adding 'c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
adding 'c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\docume~1\ajr\locals~1\temp\tmpwvnr2c\src.win32-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\scripts\f2py.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 588, in main
    run_compile()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 574, in run_compile
    setup(ext_modules = [ext])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 186, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 37, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
 self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 92, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 556, in new_compiler
    compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 127, in __init__
    elif self.gcc_version < "4.":
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 138, in __cmp__
    other = StrictVersion(other)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.parse(vstring)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 107, in parse
    raise ValueError, "invalid version number '%s'" % vstring
ValueError: invalid version number '4.'
```

Answer (score 2):

The distutils plugin for mingw32 uses an incompatible version string. In distutils/version.py, line 100, the version string matching regex is

```
r'^(\d+) \. (\d+) (\. (\d+))? ([ab](\d+))?$'
```

Edit the file `mingw32ccompiler.py` manually and change line 127 to read

```
elif self.gcc_version < "4.0":
```

Comment: Thankyou ever so much! This did the trick and I am now happily compiling Fortran.....